# Android bringToFront GridView Issue

Tags: android, gridview, foreground, behind

I'm developing an app which contains an image at the upper half of the screen and a gridview in the half below, like this:

```
<de.test.gridview.Image
    android:id="@+id/image_container"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:fadingEdgeLength="0dp"
    android:scrollbars="none"
    android:visibility="gone" />


<de.test.gridview.DraggableGridView
    android:id="@+id/grid_view1"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_below="@id/topnews_container"
    android:background="#FFF"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:numColumns="auto_fit"
    android:stretchMode="none"
    android:tag="grid_view_tag" >
</de.test.gridview.DraggableGridView>
```

The Image is set to visibility=gone and set to visible in the code manually later on.
 When I now drag on of the childs of the gridview I cant be able to drag them over the image in the upper half of the screen. They are always behind the image, but never in front of it. I've tried to use

```
gridView.bringToFront()
```

and also within the gridView I tried this function. I also tried this on the children of the gridview with gridView.bringChildToFront(child). But nothing worked.

Does anybody have an idea?

Comment: Nobody got an idea? ... :(

Answer (score 0):

I guess view with property set to View.GONE is not operational via `bringToFront()`. So I believe the following will work (if you are trying to bring the grid to the front/top of z):

```
gridView.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
gridView.bringToFront();
```

But its looks like you want to bring imageView to the front (making gridView behind instead of front). If so you need to:

```
imageView.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
imageView.bringToFront();
```